# Location of optical centre in Lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

The simple definition of optical center for a convex or concave lens was given as point through which a ray passing suffers no deviation from its path, but is there any geometrical location of this point? (i.e. the point of intersection of principal axis and radical plane of two spheres containing centers of curvature or something along the lines of this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ask yourself, *why do I need to know the location of the optical centre of a lens?*

For simple ray diagrams a lens has no thickness and it is the position of the intersection of the (no thickness) lens and the principal axis of the lens.

Once a thick lens is considered then the concept of the optical centre of a lens ceases to be useful.
The principal axis can still be defined but a ray inclined to the principal axis will undergo two refraction's, one entering the lens and the other leaving the lens.
However an outgoing ray can be parallel to the incoming ray but there will be lateral displacement of the ray and the position at which that ray crosses the principal axis will not necessarily be the same as that for another ray which entering at another angle of incidence.

[Ray tracing through a thick lens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVdNjqyvJRI) is a series of videos in which the term *optical centre* is never used.